# When I tried to create comment to micropost I have an error as "undefined method `comment_content'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I create a comment for micropost I have an error that "undefined method `comment_content'" and there is an problem on @comment.save method.

Please help me to fix the problem. Thank you for your attentions.

**comments_controller**

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.micropost = @micropost
  @comment.user = current_user
   if @comment.save
     flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
     redirect_to current_user
   else
     render 'shared/_comment_form'
   end
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
```

**_comment_form**

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.text_area :content %>
   </div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">
      Create
    </button>
 <% end %>
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :micropost
belongs_to :user

validates :comment_content, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :micropost_id, presence: true
```

**static_pages_controller**

```
 def home
  if logged_in?
  @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @comment = Comment.new
end
end
```

**_micropost.html.erb**

```
 <%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost %>
```

Comment: please include the full error stack. Do you have comment_content column, and did you run the migrations?

Comment: You are right I've no comment_column.. I changed the name the column name and now it is working :)

Comment: @bosskovic .. Also can you explain me how can I display the comments in User or Static_pages_controller and how can I write the _comments.html.erb for display the comments? Thank you so much for your attention..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can start by improving your action by doing this:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params.merge(micropost_id: params[:micropost_id], user: current_user))
    # ....
  end
```

You are validating the presence of the field "comment_content" here:

```
 validates :comment_content, presence: true
```

However, it seems that your column is called "content". Are you sure that you shouldn't put :

```
validates :content, presence: true
```

Check in your config/schema.rb to see if the name is "content" or "comment_content". Also check that you have ran your migrations with rake db:migrate.

Comment: Yes, you are correct :) I've done both of them your solutions.. Thank you so much for your attentions

Comment: Also can you explain me how can I display the comments in User or Static_pages_controller and how can I write the _comments.html.erb for display the comments? Thank you so much for your attention..